# Exporting nodejs REST paths (with express)

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple working NodeJS test app with express, mongodb and mongoose. As for now, I'm trying to clean my code a bit and to find what are the best practices. One of my steps is to extract REST routes but I have a problem in doing that also I'm confused by the amount of ways one can do it, what is the best way to do it in 2016?

My code (app.js):

```
"use strict"
const express    = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose   = require('mongoose');

const Subjects = require('./models/Subjects').model('Subjects');
const Students = require('./models/Students').model('Students');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/schoolapp');

app.get('/subjects', function(req, res) {
    Subjects.find({})
        .exec(function(err, subjects) {
            if(err) {
                res.send('error msg has occured');
            } else {
                res.json(subjects);
            }
        })
});

app.put('/subjects', function(req, res) {
    const query = {name: req.body.name};
    const update = {$inc: {votes: 1}};

    Subjects.findOneAndUpdate(query, update,
        function(err, newSubject) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('An error occured');
            } else {
                res.send(newSubject);
            }
        })
})

app.post('/subjects', function(req, res) {
    let newSubject = new Subjects();

    newSubject.name = req.body.name;
    newSubject.level = req.body.level;
    newSubject.votes = 0;

    newSubject.save(function(err, subject) {
        if(err) {
            res.send('error saving subject');
        } else {
            res.send(subject);
        }
    })
});

app.get('/students', function(req, res) {
    Students.find({})
        .exec(function(err, students) {
            if(err) {
                res.send('error saving students');
            } else {
                res.send(students);
            }
        })
})

app.post('/students', function(req, res) {
    let newStudent = new Students();

    newStudent.name = req.body.name;

    newStudent.save(function(err, student) {
        if(err) {
            res.send('error saving student');
        } else {
            res.send(student);
        }
    })
})

app.put('/students', function(req, res) {
    const query = {"_id": req.body.id};
    const update = {$push: {subjects: req.body.name}};

    Students.findOneAndUpdate(query, update,
        function(err, newSubject) {
            if(err) {
                res.send('something went wrong');
            } else {
                res.send(newSubject);
            }
        });
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('app listening on port 3000');
});
```

I want to extract `/students` and `/subjects` as separate files and require them in my app.js.

---

I have tried about 3 methods with different results, including:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/students', ...)
}
```

and in app.js:

```
var students = require(./rest/students)(app);
```

Many thanks :)

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router

Comment: Yes, @mh-cbon is right: this is a perfect case for using multiple routers.

Comment: I'm not going to serve html templates, I just want to use node as a rest api, is this still a perfect case for multiple routers?

Comment: yes it is, routers are here to help to modularize your app.

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted it out thanks to mh-cbon. I just wanted to post my solution here in case someone else will be looking for a question.

app.js

```
'use strict';
const express    = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose   = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use('/subjects', require('./rest/subjects'));
app.use('/students', require('./rest/students'));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/schoolapp');

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('app listening on port 3000');
});
```

students.js

```
'use strict';
const Students = require('../models/Students').model('Students');
const express  = require('express');
let router     = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Students.find({})
        .exec(function(err, students) {
            if(err) {
                res.send('error saving students');
            } else {
                res.send(students);
            }
        })
})

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    let newStudent = new Students();

    newStudent.name = req.body.name;

    newStudent.save(function(err, student) {
        if(err) {
            res.send('error saving student');
        } else {
            res.send(student);
        }
    })
})

router.put('/', function(req, res) {
    const query = {"_id": req.body.id};
    const update = {$push: {subjects: req.body.name}};

    Students.findOneAndUpdate(query, update,
        function(err, newSubject) {
            if(err) {
                res.send('something went wrong');
            } else {
                res.send(newSubject);
            }
        });
})

module.exports = router;
```

Note: specifying the path in app.js through `./rest/subjects` will make your paths in modules root `'/'` (see students.js), unlike in some tutorials.

I also found this article useful (since it shows a simple example):
https://www.terlici.com/2014/09/29/express-router.html